# cordova android background process

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, background-process

I'm currently trying to make a cordova app for android.

The end goal is to make an app that will unlock a door when the phone come near it. To achieve this, I believe that I need to setup a custom plugins that will handle the interaction with the door.

So far I got the basic of the application. I got the cordova interface with a bluetooth plugin that let me detect the door(in my case any bluetooth device that emulate it), I can stock the bluetooth ID in the local storage. I'm able to connect to it and send/receive data.

What I need to know, is how can I declare a background service that will be wake up by the system, that doesn't involve the UI nor the mainActivity (since I don't have access to it with cordova)

I'm not sure how must I declare the service, how must I register it so that the system will know it must not wake up the app (because the cordova core will do nothing with it) but only the plugin class that will by able to handle it.

I was looking at [android beacon library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) but I didn't know how to integrate it in a plugin since they register the thing in the main class of the application in the onCreate (I don't think I have access to that in cordova)

Any help would be really helpfull. Thank in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to setup an android service? Or are you asking how to make a plugin that would run a service and won't start the webview? I understand what your project, but the questions is not very clear.

Comment: What I want to know is how to make a service that will be wake up by the system that do not required the UI or the mainActivity class to work (cause I obviously don't have access to cordova mainActivity class XD)